Why don't the timestamps in /var/cache/yum change after `yum makecache`?
Environment: CentOS 7.6.1810 + yum-3.4.3-161.el7.centos.noarch
We found there were some strange phenomena with the timestamps of the subdir/files under the /var/cachec/yum in one of our CentOS systems. That is, after running the yum makecache subcmd, the timestamps of the subdir 7 (cachedir) and the timedhosts(.txt) files would not update.
Notes: with all other normal systems, at most only the timestamp of the timedhosts.txt file not updated after running the yum makecache subcmd.
And also all the subdir/files' contents (including repo metadata) themselves have no any change, just only their timestamps updated.
# yum makecache fast
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
centos                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 5.3 kB  00:00:00     
zabbix                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Metadata Cache Created
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 86 May 26  2020 7 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   87 May 26  2020 timedhosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  9 18:25 timedhosts.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 26 22:08 zabbix
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 26 22:08 epel
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jun 26 22:08 centos
# 

Notes: here the above outputs at that time was just Jun 26 22:08 2024
So my questions:

What factors would result in such abnormal phenomena (the timestamps of these special subdir/files not updated via yum makecache)?

What is the mechanism about the timestamps updating of these special subdir/files with or w/o the yum makecache subcmd?
Notes: because we occasionally found that sometimes the timedhosts(.txt) files would automatically update their own timestamps.




Now I have run the following six tests with both the two yum repolist and the four makecache: 

first   time: yum repolist           only the timedhosts.txt updated its timestamp despite it was still empty
second  time: yum repolist           nothing updated 
third   time: yum -d10 makecahe      the relevant repo subdirs plus its parent dir 7 and just the timedhosts updated despite the source repos nothing changed 
fourth  time: yum -d10 makecahe      the relevant repo subdirs plus its parent dir 7 and just the timedhosts updated despite the source repos nothing changed 
fifth   time: yum -d10 makecahe      just the relevant repo subdirs updated despite the source repos nothing changed 
sixth   time: yum -d10 makecahe      still the relevant repo subdirs updated despite the source repos nothing changed 



# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 15 May 25  2020 x86_64
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 263 Jul 29 11:30 7
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 core-0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 25  2020 ceph
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 base
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos-ceph-luminous
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 updates
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 extras
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 May 25  2020 ceph1326
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 Jul 29 10:10 CentOS74_zlocal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Jul 29 11:30 timedhosts
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  254 Jul 29 11:30 zabbix
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 29 11:30 epel
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  254 Jul 29 11:30 ceph1322
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 26 16:43 timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# 
# date
Wed Nov  6 17:53:35 CST 2024
# 
# 
# lsattr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts.txt
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# lsattr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/CentOS74_zlocal
total 3136
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3008 May 17 15:39 repomd.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3205626 May 17 15:39 b36cf48077a5b0fd8546b54c50f4c22192ab6eb699e7037abe19617b1f7dfd05-primary.sqlite.bz2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       6 Jul  4 17:11 packages
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      31 Jul  4 17:11 gen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 Jul 19 15:19 cachecookie
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2985 May 25  2020 repomd.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24736 May 25  2020 b10dac0e957b94267433e5de7ff82e67626d774e703f8e43307fad088764ebbe-filelists.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26579 May 25  2020 291a4b561c9eb5c84b77d44c42ac040a6ea6e10a348a71afea555b3777e86025-primary.sqlite.bz2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     6 May 26  2020 packages
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    58 Sep  4  2023 gen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jul 29 11:30 cachecookie
# 
# 
# 
# lsattr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix/gen
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix/packages
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix/repomd.xml
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix/cachecookie
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix/291a4b561c9eb5c84b77d44c42ac040a6ea6e10a348a71afea555b3777e86025-primary.sqlite.bz2
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix/b10dac0e957b94267433e5de7ff82e67626d774e703f8e43307fad088764ebbe-filelists.sqlite.bz2
# 
# 
# 
# lsattr /etc/hosts
---------------- /etc/hosts
# 
# 
# lsattr /etc/passwd
---------------- /etc/passwd
# 
# 
# 
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Determining fastest mirrors
repo id                                                                                                             repo name                                                                                                         status
!ceph1322                                                                                                           ceph                                                                                                                 122
!epel                                                                                                               ceph                                                                                                              13,237
!zabbix                                                                                                             zabbix                                                                                                                41
repolist: 13,400
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/|grep time
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Jul 29 11:30 timedhosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# 
# lsattr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/time*
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# 
# cat /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/time*.txt
# 
# 
# cat /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/time*.txt
# 
# 
# 
# cat /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
file:///centos_7.4_zlocal/ 318924300 0 1720084300
192.168.89.5 221489998 0 1722223838
# 
# 
# 
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                                                                                                             repo name                                                                                                         status
!ceph1322                                                                                                           ceph                                                                                                                 122
!epel                                                                                                               ceph                                                                                                              13,237
!zabbix                                                                                                             zabbix                                                                                                                41
repolist: 13,400
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/|grep time
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Jul 29 11:30 timedhosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# 
# lsattr -v /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/time*
744450882 ---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
18446744071977162174 ---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# 
# 
# uptime
 18:12:51 up 1626 days,  2:00,  2 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.06, 0.06
# 
# 
# 
# yum -d10 makecache
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Config time: 0.008
Yum version: 3.4.3
ceph1322                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 5.3 kB  00:00:00     
zabbix                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
(1/4): ceph1322/other_db                                                                                                                                                                                             |  46 kB  00:00:00     
(2/4): epel/other_db                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 3.2 MB  00:00:00     
(3/4): epel/prestodelta                                                                                                                                                                                              |  431 B  00:00:00     
(4/4): zabbix/other_db                                                                                                                                                                                               |  26 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Metadata Cache Created
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 core-0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 25  2020 ceph
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 base
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos-ceph-luminous
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 updates
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 extras
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 May 25  2020 ceph1326
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 Jul 29 10:10 CentOS74_zlocal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:13 zabbix
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Nov  6 18:13 timedhosts
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:13 epel
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:13 ceph1322
# 
# 
# 
# lsattr -v /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/time*
18446744071745090135 ---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
18446744071977162174 ---------------- /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts.txt
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 263 Nov  6 18:13 7
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 15 May 25  2020 x86_64
# 
# 
# 
# 
# cat /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
file:///centos_7.4_zlocal/ 318924300 0 1720084300
192.168.89.5 221332139 0 1730887991
# 
#  
# 
# uptime
 18:18:25 up 1626 days,  2:05,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.03, 0.05
# 
# 
# 
# yum -d10 makecache
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Config time: 0.008
Yum version: 3.4.3
ceph1322                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 5.3 kB  00:00:00     
zabbix                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Metadata Cache Created
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 263 Nov  6 18:18 7
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 core-0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 25  2020 ceph
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 base
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos-ceph-luminous
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 updates
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 extras
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 May 25  2020 ceph1326
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 Jul 29 10:10 CentOS74_zlocal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:18 zabbix
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Nov  6 18:18 timedhosts
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:18 epel
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:18 ceph1322
# 
# 
# 
# cat /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
file:///centos_7.4_zlocal/ 318924300 0 1720084300
192.168.89.5 221319855 0 1730888314
# 
# 
# 
# uptime
 18:35:36 up 1626 days,  2:23,  2 users,  load average: 0.15, 0.07, 0.06
# 
# 
# yum -d10 makecache
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Config time: 0.008
Yum version: 3.4.3
ceph1322                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 5.3 kB  00:00:00     
zabbix                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Metadata Cache Created
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 263 Nov  6 18:18 7
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 core-0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 25  2020 ceph
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 base
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos-ceph-luminous
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 updates
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 extras
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 May 25  2020 ceph1326
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 Jul 29 10:10 CentOS74_zlocal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Nov  6 18:18 timedhosts
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:35 zabbix
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:35 epel
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:35 ceph1322
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 263 Nov  6 18:18 7
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7|grep time
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Nov  6 18:18 timedhosts
# 
# 
# cat /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/timedhosts
file:///centos_7.4_zlocal/ 318924300 0 1720084300
192.168.89.5 221319855 0 1730888314
# 
# 
# 
# uptime
 18:51:06 up 1626 days,  2:38,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.05, 0.05
# 
# 
# 
# yum -d10 makecache
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "priorities" plugin
Config time: 0.008
Yum version: 3.4.3
ceph1322                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 5.3 kB  00:00:00     
zabbix                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Metadata Cache Created
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 263 Nov  6 18:18 7
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 core-0
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 25  2020 ceph
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 base
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos-ceph-luminous
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 updates
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 extras
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   33 May 25  2020 centos
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 May 25  2020 ceph1326
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  161 Jul 29 10:10 CentOS74_zlocal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Nov  6 18:18 timedhosts
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:51 zabbix
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:51 epel
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:51 ceph1322
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/|grep time
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  6 17:56 timedhosts.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   86 Nov  6 18:18 timedhosts
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel
total 24500
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    89651 Jun 24  2019 d97ad2922a45eb2a5fc007fdd84e7ae4981b257d3b94c3c9f5d7b0dda6baa098-comps-Everything.x86_64.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3375137 Jun 24  2019 eabda555e71ba756172c4dd78b32c9ce1ba759d7ed798d05e2d98e7bd125065b-other.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7079263 Jun 24  2019 a03015cd83fc6c42d0b41a197bd5504184da66787b1bf0cd44ce5b3312531d8e-primary.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12013825 Jun 24  2019 7ddfabd3875d7e02db5f33e403ec73d50417a69da4d0d8ac8dcf336745a21b4e-filelists.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      431 Jun 24  2019 dff09d8780f079208f89cb8736e5237c2ef6de3367ad438b4d7ac88f8c005587-prestodelta.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1001489 Jun 24  2019 bb50f16f63c496bfb39ef72cc6e79569600ec4cfb2624e0b96565e1d090c85fd-updateinfo.xml.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1502824 Jun 24  2019 db1c409bc28dbf5797d01d27bf0768dc52f651d5ae33dfea145e28ec1e4bff88-updateinfo.xml.zck
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     5477 Jun 24  2019 repomd.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 May 25  2020 metalink.xml.tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        6 Jul  2 10:48 packages
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      121 Nov  6 18:13 gen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Nov  6 18:51 cachecookie
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/gen
total 118364
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   373476 Jun 24  2019 comps.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18419712 Jun 24  2019 other_db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30322688 Jun 24  2019 primary_db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 72081408 Jun 24  2019 filelists_db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1021 Jun 24  2019 prestodelta.xml
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix
total 88
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2985 May 25  2020 repomd.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 24736 May 25  2020 b10dac0e957b94267433e5de7ff82e67626d774e703f8e43307fad088764ebbe-filelists.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26275 May 25  2020 4f18be95f3e43d1846d5568d214ec3601b0adf8b70dae96878bc6aa9d8726219-other.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 26579 May 25  2020 291a4b561c9eb5c84b77d44c42ac040a6ea6e10a348a71afea555b3777e86025-primary.sqlite.bz2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     6 May 26  2020 packages
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    81 Nov  6 18:13 gen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Nov  6 18:51 cachecookie
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/zabbix/gen
total 636
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 180224 May 25  2020 primary_db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 294912 May 25  2020 other_db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176128 May 25  2020 filelists_db.sqlite
# 
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/ceph1322
total 352
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2991 May 25  2020 repomd.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47001 May 25  2020 de0ea872738ebfed799765286ef34c3f04ea0c720125fd7ae38eb90f9eeaeba8-other.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 186749 May 25  2020 68ded87e4a6ed2fba9b2a5ba624d58128beb17a6d58e50d4ccce368cac78c7c8-primary.sqlite.bz2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116990 May 25  2020 2a60b4833ca445f05f7efb71f4bf40150899cd25c9d0ad4ec2f4c4e431e51fac-filelists.sqlite.bz2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      6 May 27  2020 packages
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     81 Nov  6 18:13 gen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Nov  6 18:51 cachecookie
# 
# 
# ls -ltr /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/ceph1322/gen
total 1976
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1203200 May 25  2020 primary_db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  195584 May 25  2020 other_db.sqlite
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  619520 May 25  2020 filelists_db.sqlite
# 
# 


Try running ls -ltcr (notice the -c, read in the man).

The same result with ls -ltrcr .....

1. What factors could lead to timestamps not updating with yum makecache?

Cache hit: If the repository metadata on the remote mirrors hasn’t changed since the last cache update, yum might not need to fetch new metadata files. In such cases, yum may skip updating certain cache files or directories entirely, meaning timestamps won’t change. yum makecache typically refreshes only if new metadata is detected. This only applies to your case if you purge your cache
File system behavior (hard links or attributes): Sometimes, certain file attributes (e.g., immutable or noatime) can prevent files from updating their timestamps as expected. Using lsattr on these files can reveal such attributes. My guess would be that unless your mirror speeds change, yum would continue to creating hard link to same disk sector with the file to prevent re-caching identical content. Check your /proc/mounts.
Somw yum plugins or custom scripts: Certain yum plugins (such as fastestmirror, langpacks, or priorities) might affect caching behaviors by altering the cached metadata handling. Additionally, custom scripts or system-specific configurations that run before or after yum commands could modify or reset timestamps.

2. How does the mechanism for timestamp updating work for these files and directories?
When running yum makecache, yum goes through a general process for updating cache and timestamps, which involves:

Checking Local Cache vs. Remote Metadata: yum first verifies if local cached metadata is up-to-date. If not, it downloads the latest metadata. This action updates the timestamps on downloaded files or directories (/var/cache/yum/ and subdirectories for specific repositories).
Updating timedhosts files: timedhosts and timedhosts.txt files track mirror host timings for selecting the fastest mirrors. timedhosts.txt updates ONLY if the fastest mirror changes or if it’s explicitly refreshed by yum makecache. This file may be skipped for updating if there was no change in mirror timing, which could explain why its timestamp sometimes updates and sometimes doesn’t. Paired with hard links, this would allow yum to skip new I/O if identical file was already written.

3. Why might timedhosts(.txt) files occasionally update their own timestamps automatically?
The timedhosts.txt file updates under specific conditions:

Mirror speed re-evaluation: The timedhosts.txt file updates when yum re-evaluates mirror speeds (e.g., after the fastestmirror plugin re-checks and finds different optimal mirrors).
Automatic or periodic yum Updates: yum on CentOS has a built-in timer for checking repositories, so if this timer is reached, it might refresh timedhosts.txt.
Manual or scripted cache clearing: Scripts may clear out `/var/cache/yum/, forcing YUM to refresh the cache upon the next run, which would update timestamps across all relevant files.

You might want to check:
Verify File Attributes: Use lsattr on timedhosts, timedhosts.txt, and other files to ensure they’re not marked with unusual attributes (e.g., i for immutable).
Test with Debug Mode: Running yum -v makecache for verbose output or yum -d 10 makecache for debugging output can give more detailed information about the caching process and why it may or may not be updating specific files.
Check your file system attirbutes. Various flags such as cow & noatime might affect whether file gets updated timestamps even after pulling identical content

The problem still foucses on the timestamp of the timedhosts(.txt) and the cache dir 7.
a). Why he timedhosts(.txt) could have not been updated for more than 2 months？
b). Why the cache dir 7 have not been updated for the last two yum makecache ?
